# Webpack importar css junto com component REACTJS

Tags: react, npm, webpack

Olá,

estou fazendo um component (REACTJS), gostaria de ao importar o css viesse.
Estou utilizando o `css-loader` e `style-loader`.

Como nunca tinha feito algo assim, não sei se a configuração está correta.

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve('dist')
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            cacheDirectory: true
          }
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*Projeto no NPM* :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/slidal

Quando instalo, eu consigo usar o componente, mas o css não vem junto.

Comment: Opa cara, vou remover a resposta já que não foi útil. Queria te trazer uma solução pra evitar todo esses stress, que seria utilizar StyledComponent ou JSS, daí não seria necessário importar nenhum estilo css e tudo estaria dentro do JS. Observa a forma que o MaterialUI trabalha, é bem interessante.

Comment: Já trabalhei com ambas as soluções na criação de libs, e funcionou bem.

Comment: Solucionei utilizando o `style from '.....` e utilizar em cada lugar dentro do component o style in line e não utilizando nome de classes com `--`, mudando o padrão para maiusculo